# Dart - Null Operators

Tags: dart

I need something like:

```
if (variable != null) {
  otherVariable = variable;
}
```

Is there a neater way to write this with NullOperators? All I came up with is:

```
(variable != null) ? otherVariable = variable : null;
```

Comment: What should be the value of `otherVariable` in case `variable` **is** equal to null?

Comment: If it should be equivalent to the first example, there should be no assignment to `otherVariable` if `variable` is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no special operator in Dart which allows an assignment to be dependent on the *assigned* value being non-null.

The closest operator is [`??=`](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators) where `otherVariable ??= variable;` does the opposite of what you want: It assigns `variable` to `otherVariable` if *`otherVariable`* is `null`, not if `variable` is non-null.

You could use [`??`](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators) and go with `otherVariable = variable ?? otherVariable;`, which assigns the current value of `otherVariable` back to itself if `variable` is `null`. It still performs an assignment in that case, which might be detectable if `otherVariable` is a *setter*.

I'd just go with `if (variable != null) otherVariable = variable;`. It's currently the shortest code which does *exactly* what you want: Assign to `otherVariable` *only* if `variable` is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way would be  :

```
otherVariable = (variable != null) ? variable : null;
```

But in your case, if it is null, then why do you assign it 'null' when variable is already null? You could have done this:

```
otherVariable = variable;
```

In both the codes same thing happens. Use the Second code as it is short, and use the first one if you have to replace the 'null' by something else like this:

```
otherVariable = (variable != null) ? variable : 'default';
```

Comment: Consider using null aware operator `??`

Comment: It makes good sense to only update `otherVariable` if `variable` is non-null. For example `variable` could be an optional parameter `updateFoos({int? variable, ...}) { if (variable != null) otherVariable = varaiable; }`.

Comment: @dev-aengts Using the `??` operator is not a good fit for this problem.

Comment: Yes @lrn I understand now with respect to your answer that `??` would still perform assignment when it could be avoided conditionally. Sir but what would the impact like would it be considered bad practice (agreed it might confuse the future maintainer) or would it have other undesired problems?

Comment: If the assignment has side effects, which can happen if it's a setter because then maybe it fires an "change" event when the value is set, then calling a setter can be significantly different from not calling it. (Sure, it should probably check that the value is actually *different* before firing "change" events). Otherwise it's just inefficient to assign the value, and the code doesn't reflect the original intent, which is bad for maintainance. In this case, it's just not what the original question asked for.